# GCE Instance Boot Disk Image Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I wonder if someone can help.

I have some running instances.  I'd like to get the image name of an instance boot disk (e.g., *debian-10-buster-v20200618*).  It shows in the GCP console but neither of these commands fetch it:

```
gcloud compute instances list
gcloud compute instances list --format=json
```

Is there a way for GCloud to access this value?  Could something (JS?) go directly to an API?  Perhaps accessing the image family would be more useful but that probably needs to be derived from the image name.  Could be that I'm missing something obvious :/

Any thoughts or suggestions gratefully received!

Rik

**Solution**
Create an instance

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west1-b
```

Determine the image on which it was based

```
gcloud compute disks describe instance-1 --zone=europe-west1-b --format=json |
jq -r .sourceImage
```

(I've used JQ to filter down the response; W_B -- many thanks BTW -- uses Awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list disks with `[gcloud compute disks list][1]`.

> [The disk name is usually same as the instance name.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk#detach_disk)

The name you provided (`debian-10-buster-v20200618`) looks more like an [image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) name of the disk. You can use `gcloud compute images list` in the same way as `disks list`.

If you want just the first column displayed and sorted by nanme then you can do `gcloud compute disks list --sort-by=NAME | awk '{print $1}'`.

This is just an example of what you can do - if you specify your desired output then I can edit my answer.

Here's [how to use AWK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/) to process any text output and make it more suited for your needs.

If you specify what's you desired output of this command I will edit the question and post exact command.

If the sorting capabilities of the `gcloud` arent enough you can use built in [`sort` command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-command-linuxunix-examples/).

---

**To get a source image name which VM's disk was created from use `gcloud compute disks describe yourinstancename --zone=myzone | grep image`.**

The result will look simillar to this:
`https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2012-r2-dc-v20200609`

You can further use AWK to "tidy up" the results and get just the image name (for scripting etc).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did not explain myself properly.  If you look at a VM details' page, in the boot disk section: the first column is *Name*, which, as you point out, is usually the same as the instance name -- it is the value of the second column *Image*, which displays the name of the image, that I'd like to retrieve.  `gcloud compute images list` does contain that value but it does not tie it to the instances that are based on it.  That is, with an instance's name, say *instance-1*, I'd like to retrieve the image from which the boot disk of instance-1 was built.

Comment: Thanks for explanation - I've edited my answer to include image name.

Comment: That's excellent -- just what I need -- thank you!  Just FTR:
`gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west1-b; gcloud compute disks describe instance-1 --zone=europe-west1-b --format=json | jq -r .sourceImage`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - if my answer helped you I would appreciate accepting it :)

Comment: sorry, thought I had; done now and thanks again!